# Placing a dialog in a segment of a page in angular 2+

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

We have a component in angular2+ as a modal pop-up and we want to make use of that component in the angularJS application. and we were able to achieve that
We want that pop-up to look like normal content in a div tag rather than a popup in an angularJS application

We want to place that popup inside a segment of the page to make it look like a part of the page instead of a pop-up (we removed the backdrop and the shadow of the popup to make it look like a part of the page)
Is it possible to do it?
How can we achieve it?

Comment: You can use https://material.angular.io/. I believe it gives the best dialogs which can be customized easily. You can also check out this article: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box. It walks you through creating a pop-up modal.